# Attributes of semantic rules

Tags: semantics, context-free-grammar, rules

I've these rules:

```
S -> I#A
I -> a
I -> b
A -> aA
A -> bA
A -> EPSILON
```

This grammar produces a sequence of `a's` and `b's`. They are preceded by a single `a` (or a single `b`) and an `#`. I need to define semantic rules which gives me the number of a's or b's (it depends on which one I choose before the #) after the #.
I don't know how to start because the value of A (in the first rule) depends on the value of I. How do I pass 'a' or 'b' to A?

Comment: A context free grammar doesn't "give" you anything except a bunch of rules for deriving strings in a language. What do you want to *do* with the numbers of a's and of b's once you get them? Or, what system are you working in that adds "semantic rules" to context free grammars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what the question is, but as in the comment the grammar is used to read in a string. You can look at the rules as if they are describing a tree where the left hand side is the parent and the right hand side are the children.

So in your system there seems to be an alphabet which consists of {a, b, EPSILON, #}. Therefore if you have the input string of a#b you would get the following tree

```
S ---  I -- a
  ---  #
  ---  A -- b
         -- A -- EPSILON
```

So S has the children of **I**, **#** and **A** ( **S -> I # A**), **I** has a child of **a** (**I -> a**). **A** has two children **b** and **A (A -> b A)** and the last **A** has a single child **EPSILON**

After this you can then add in semantic rules such as conditions to your grammar also known as an attribute grammar.